# Possible to override classes with specific element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

CSS newbie here wondering if this is possible. If I have something like the code below, is it possible to override just the section that has the class itemtile AND data-id of ABC123? My goal is to hide that entire section from being displayed. I've reviewed some past comments about specifity but when it comes to wanting both values to exist I get a bit lost. I'm mucking with trying to override code for a site that is not mine using a personal plugin.

```
<div id="itemgrid" class="section">
<div class="itemtile" data-id="ABC123">
    <div class="itemcontent"></div>
</div>
<div class="itemtile" data-id="DEF123">
    <div class="itemcontent"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

I did some code examination in the debugger and can make the page do what I want by removing the div element for the data-id's I want to hide just not sure how to do it in CSS.  I'm not asking for help on creating the plugin just if and how I can address an element that specifically.

Comment: .itemtile[data-id='ABC123']

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this with `JavaScript`

```js
let class = document.getElementsByClassName("itemtile"); 

for(let i = 0; i < class.length; i++){ 
    if(class[i].dataset.id == 'ABC123'){
         class[i].style.display = "none";
         break;
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to do this using `CSS`, you can do it like so:

```css
.itemtile[data-id='ABC123'] {
    display: none;
}
```

That should do it!

Comment: I appreciate the code example. I take it not doable via CSS then?  I'm not sure how to hide the section using JS I can see this finds the class and how but how do I hide it or does this example do that as well?

Comment: @CM42 This is doable via `CSS` as well, you can do this by using `.itemtile[data-id='ABC123'] {display: none;}`. Although I would recommend `JS`.

Comment: @CM42, I've also updated my original answer to show how you can hide the element using `JavaScript`, if that's the way you want to go. I also suggested an edit to your question, take a look :)

Answer (score 0):

You can override easily by adding `style=""` after your div

for example

```
<div style="" id="itemgrid" class="section">
```